# cgroups not working properly with multi-core DPDK application

Tags: performance, cpu, lxc, cpu-load

I want to restrict the CPU usage of a DPDK application for testing. After some quick search I found that Control Groups (cgroups) might suit my needs. So first I installed `cgroup-bin`.

```
sudo apt-get install cgroup-bin
```

And then I created a subsystem by creating a directory under `/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu`.

```
mkdir -v /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/dpdk
```

And then I write my restrictions to CPU usage to `cpu.cfs_period_us` and `cpu.cfs_quota_us`. For example, I want to restrict the CPU usage of my  DPDK application at 30%.

```
cd /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/dpdk
echo 1000000 > cpu.cfs_period_us
echo 300000 > cpu.cfs_quota_us
```

This approach works when running DPDK applications which uses only one core. For example, the basic forward sample application at `examples/skeleton`

```
cd /home/wang/dpdk-17.02/examples/skeleton
make
./build/basicfwd -c 1 -n 2
pgrep basicfwd > /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/dpdk/tasks
```

I can see in `top` that the CPU usage of basicfwd is actually at 30%.

```
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                  
3346 root      20   0 4222472   3100   2780 R  30.0  0.0   0:56.35 basicfwd
```

However when I run a DPDK application which uses more than one core. The result is a little bit weird. For example, I want to run the L3 forward sample application at `examples/l3fwd`.

```
cd /home/wang/dpdk-17.02/examples/l3fwd
make
./build/l3fwd -l 1,2 -n 2 -- -p 0x3 -P --config="(0,0,1),(1,0,2)" --parse-ptype
pgrep l3fwd > /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/dpdk/tasks
```

When I open `top`, I see that the CPU usage of `l3fwd` is at 130%, rather than 30% which is what I expected.

```
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                  
3404 root      20   0 4305752   5092   2728 R 130.3  0.0   0:25.98 l3fwd
```

It seems the restrictions is applied to only one core. However in [this page](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Resource_Management_Guide/sec-cpu.html) it says that the quota and period parameters operate on a CPU basis

> cpu.cfs_quota_us
>
> specifies the total amount of time in microseconds (µs, represented here as "us") for which all tasks in a cgroup can run during one period (as defined by cpu.cfs_period_us). As soon as tasks in a cgroup use up all the time specified by the quota, they are throttled for the remainder of the time specified by the period and not allowed to run until the next period. If tasks in a cgroup should be able to access a single CPU for 0.2 seconds out of every 1 second, set cpu.cfs_quota_us to 200000 and cpu.cfs_period_us to 1000000. Note that the quota and period parameters operate on a CPU basis. To allow a process to fully utilize two CPUs, for example, set cpu.cfs_quota_us to 200000 and cpu.cfs_period_us to 100000.

What am I missing here? What should I do to restrict the CPU usage of a multi-core DPDK application to under 100%?

Comment: I just started looking into the issue itself, but I scratch my had on the scenario a bit. I like to refer to DPDK as "burn all my CPU to make things faster for some cases". If you want to restrict CPU on DPDK for anything else than experiments I'd recommend to just not use DPDK at all IMHO - nor scheduling DPDK for 700ms doesn't sound right :-). Anyway trying to look into the real issue now.

Comment: @ChristianEhrhardt Thank you for your help and advice. It was just for experiments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

- use `for i in $(pgrep -w l3fwd); do echo $i > tasks; done`

**Details:**

I think in your case the pgrep to task assignment needs some improvement to work with multiple IDs being reported.

If it returns one PID things work just fine, but if it returns more the cgroup interface actually reports

```
pgrep: write error: Invalid argument
```

Maybe you only simplified your report, but please double check that all tasks are in the cgroups task file and use a loop (or any other workaround).

```
$ stress-ng -c 4
$ for i in $(pgrep stress); do echo $i > /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/dpdk/tasks; done
$ cat tasks 
28543
28544
[...]
```

Now for your case in particular, l3fwd has one process but three threads.
So `pgrep` will only report the main pid, the others (main loops) are unrestricted.
You can see when you build and test it via `ps axlf` vs `ps -eLf` and the `pgrep` output.

```
. /usr/share/dpdk/dpdk-sdk-env.sh
mkdir -p l3fwd
make -C /usr/share/dpdk/examples/l3fwd "O=$(pwd)/l3fwd/"
#  config /etc/dpdk/dpdk.conf and /etc/dpdk/interfaces
service dpdk restart
$(pwd)/l3fwd/l3fwd -l 1,2 --socket-mem 512 -- -p 0x3 -P --config="(0,0,1),(1,0,2)" --parse-ptype
```

So you have to take `pgrep -w` and combine it with the above.

```
for i in $(pgrep -w l3fwd); do echo $i > tasks; done
```

And e voila, from:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                   
29849 root      20   0  703052   4184   3336 R 200,7  0,0   0:17.36 l3fwd
```

to

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                   
29849 root      20   0  703052   4184   3336 R  29,8  0,0   0:34.11 l3fwd
```

Still please see my initial comment, other than for experiments please to not limit DPDK cpu consumption - then instead just do not use DPDK.

Comment: Thank you so much and your answer is really enlightening. It was just for experiments and we have no plan to limit the CPU consumption on DPDK applications in production. However in my case I managed to solve the problem in another way. I changed the config option from `--config="(0,0,1),(1,0,2)"` to `--config="(0,0,2),(1,0,1)"`, leaving everything else exactly the same, and it just worked like magic. Your solution is much better and more universal though.